# Flutter gradle compile error when using Dart 3 new features. How can I fix it?

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle

I was experimenting with new Dart 3 features but my app won't compile.

```
packages/charts_repository/lib/src/models/peak_mean.dart:35:14: Error: Expected ')' before this.
    if (json case {'DataSavedTime': final date, 'Value': final value}) {
             ^^^^
packages/charts_repository/lib/src/models/peak_mean.dart:36:38: Error: Undefined name 'date'.
      return PeakMean(DateTime.parse(date), num.parse(value));
                                     ^^^^
packages/charts_repository/lib/src/models/peak_mean.dart:36:55: Error: Undefined name 'value'.
      return PeakMean(DateTime.parse(date), num.parse(value));
                                                      ^^^^^
packages/charts_repository/lib/src/models/peak_mean.dart:35:9: Error: A value of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'bool'.
 - 'Map' is from 'dart:core'.
    if (json case {'DataSavedTime': final date, 'Value': final value}) {
```

Here is the new dart 3 feature causing the error

```
class PeakMean {
  final DateTime x;
  final num y;

  PeakMean(this.x, this.y);

  factory PeakMean.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json case {'DataSavedTime': final date, 'Value': final value}) {
      return PeakMean(DateTime.parse(date), num.parse(value));
    }
    throw const FormatException('Unexpected JSON format');
  }
}
```

Output from `flutter doctor -v`

```
• Flutter version 3.10.4 on channel stable at C:\Users\itsroom\Development\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 682aa387cf (3 days ago), 2023-06-05 18:04:56 -0500
    • Engine revision 2a3401c9bb
    • Dart version 3.0.3
    • DevTools version 2.23.1
```

`pubspec.yaml`

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=3.0.0 <4.0.0"
```

Comment: I had similar issues. Have you tried a reboot? That worked for me

Comment: `flutter pub upgrade` command solved the problem in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flutter pub upgrade` command solved the problem for me. Try upgrading your packages as well as flutter clean.